# no software with CFbundleidentifier exists

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8

I'm trying send my app(custom keyboard) for submit and catch this error:

[image]

I created Provisioning Profiles for Project(com.michilly.SakhaKeyboard) and for Extension(com.michilly.SakhaKeyboard.Keyboard)

Comment: and? as the error states you use different certificates - you didn't ask a question yet

Comment: @Daij-Djan oh sorry:( i solved my problem, but catch new error T_T I have updated my question

Comment: and? again - no question. you obviously use a bundleIdentifier for which there is no app in iTunesConnect

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Make sure the following two values match:

- The "Bundle Identifier" value in your project's Info.plist file;
- The "Bundle ID" value on the iTunes Connect website at My Apps > [your app] > More tab > About This App.

Comment: Yes, I solved my problem:) Custom keyboard extension and project have 2 different Bundle Identifiers. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The Bundle Identifider is case sensitive.

For me, I have to change in the "Supporting Files" - Info.plist - Bundle Identifer 
  from com.nebitrams.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)
  to   com.nebitrams.dandelion123

After that it works since it matches the letter case in iTunesConnect Bundle Identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Im my case I created the app with given Bundle ID, then created identifier and provisioning profiles on [Apple Developer](http://developer.apple.com) but forgot to add new app in [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com).