# No software with CFBundleIdentifier of 'xxxxxx' exists.

Tags: ios

I'm using Xcode6.0.1.I'm trying to submit my app by using Application Loader.But it gives me this error:

No software with CFBundleIdentifier of 'com.jiazhong.ios' exists.  Verify your bundle identifier is correct.  If it is, you may need to log into iTunes Connect to create the application.

But my bundle identifier in xcode are the same with the bundle id in the itunes connect.
I also try the solution in this question,[no software with CFbundleidentifier exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957309/no-software-with-cfbundleidentifier-exists,but) it doesn't work.
How to fix this error?Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and for me the problem was that I didnt have an app created in the Itunes Connect. This is not the developer.apple.com app identifier. You have to log into the Itunes Connect account and create an app. Then you can select the bundle ID you created in the Developer portal.
https://itunesconnect.apple.com

It solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and came to know that validation fails when there is no matching app in the iTunesConnect. So, validation also seems checking readiness for iTunes Store on top of other validations.